# Relation between column vectors and rank of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional and $A$ is the matrix representation of $T: U \to V$.

I see that if $U$ and $V$ have the same scalar field, then the rank of $T$ equals the maximal number of linearly independent columns (in $U$) of $A$.

But say the scalar field of $V$ properly contains that of $U$. Then a set of linearly independent columns of $A$ need not be linearly independent in $V$, so that the rank of $T$ could be strictly less than the maximal number of linearly independent columns (in $U$) of $A$.

Is this correct? Or can we always say that the rank of $T$ corresponds to the maximal number of linearly independent columns?

Comment: Is 'scalar field' really the correct term for the field the vector space is based upon? Isn't 'scalar field' a term from differential geometry?

Comment: @Babelfish: It's a field whose elements are scalars. I think "field of scalars" is more common, but natural language likes to commute that to "scalar field". Yes, "scalar field" is also used to mean something else as well. Unfortunately, many phrases in mathematics are overloaded. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have different scalar fields, then you lose the correspondence between matrices and linear transformations.

Comment: What would "linear" mean, anyway? If $k\subset K$ are the fields, then $T$ could only be $k$-linear, since $K$-linearity would not mean anything.

Comment: Well you can use restriction of scalars to interpret $V$ as a vector space over the scalar field of $U$